# Prevent Angular (click) binding if variable is 'undefined'

Tags: angular

I'm adding callbacks to a custom Angular component the normal Angular way like this: `(click)="data.callback ? data.callback() : undefined"`

This works well, so when there is no callback defined, nothing happens and Angular seems to handle the `undefined` well. BUT... Angular is still binding this click event, as you can see when logging `(this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement).eventListeners('click')` inside the custom component.

My goal is to add a `link` class to the custom component in case the dev actually added a `(click)` to it. The following code is doing it's job, as long as no `(click)` is added to the custom component.

```
  @HostBinding('class.link')
  get hasClickEvent() {
    return !!(this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement).eventListeners('click').length;
  }
```

But a `(click)="undefined"` would still add the link class unfortunately :(

I added a [Stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fwzidf?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Any ideas to solve this **without creating custom outputs**? Maybe there is also a better solution?

Comment: Can you create two separate instances of the element, using `*ngIf` based on whether `data.callback` exists?

Comment: @NickFelker Sure, but this would lead to lot of duplicate code. Imaging having something like this ;)

<app-custom [flag]="..."  
            [palette]="..."  
            [icon]="..."  
            [iconPosition]="..."  
            [iconSize]="..."  
            [disabled]="..."  
            [fullWidth]="..."  
            [loading]="..."  
            [size]="..."  
            [type]="..."  
            [updates]="..."  
            [variant]="...">  
  Foo Bar  
</app-custom>

Comment: @Vega No, it need's to bee added to the host via HostBinding like in the Stackblitz.

Comment: @Vega If I gout you right, you suggest this (https://pastebin.com/ciY4GJSX)? You see, this would duplicate the whole code. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yeah, this would work, but this way I would have to tell every developer to add a extra line of code, just to add the link class. Goal is that the component itself can decide to add the link class, depending on whether the component has a click event or not.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you get it wrong. My goal is to have a solution without a need to set [attr.data-toto] or similar. The app-custom should be able to identify existing click event bindings on its own to add the link class.

Answer (score 0):

As aggressive as this sounds, I'm sorry:

Whatever you're doing, you're probably doing it wrong.

If you expect to click something, it should be a `<button>`. Unless you expect to click it and it navigates somewhere, then it should be an `<a>`. Web semantics are a thing.

Just because you *can* make random elements clickable, doesn't necessarily mean you should.

What you have simply sounds like you just want something as simple as:

```
<button (click)="data.callback()" [disabled]="!data.callback">Something</button>
```

Then, being disabled, it won't have a click event attached (and thus no pointer styling).

Even if you didn't do this, either way you're in the realms of styling - either removing pointer events:

```css
.link.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.link.not-clickable {
  cursor: default;
}
```

or just removing whatever default 'disabled' styling the button might have so that it matches the active styling:

```css
button:disabled {
  ...
}
```